# validationError: Progress plugin invalid options VueJS

Tags: vuejs2, npm-audit, vue-cli-5

There are several vulnerabilities shows in audit fix command in my vue project. When I upgrade @vue/cli-service package to v5.0.8 from v4.5.17, I get progressPlugin error.

My other package version are:

```
"dependencies": {
"core-js": "^3.6.5",
"idle-vue": "^2.0.5",
"moment": "^2.29.4",
"text-mask-addons": "^3.8.0",
"v-mask": "^2.2.4",
"vue": "^2.6.11",
"vue-moment": "^4.1.0",
"vue-router": "^3.2.0",
"vuetify": "^2.6.13",
"vuex": "^3.4.0"
 },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass": "^1.32.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-axios": "^0.0.4",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^2.4.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.0"
  },
```

Comment: I get **ValidationError: Progress Plugin Invalid Options** I have heard the way you solve it is to uninstall and install again the dependencies. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75576820/dev-server-has-been-initialized-using-an-options-object-that-does-not-match-the/75593975?noredirect=1#comment133434793_75593975