# Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema. - options has an unknown property 'public'

Tags: django, vue.js, webpack

There was an error linking django with vuejs.

**in my vue.config.js file:**

```
const BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');

module.exports = {
  publicPath: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/',
  outputDir: './dist/',

  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.optimization.splitChunks(false)

    config.plugin('BundleTracker').use(BundleTracker, [{filename: './webpack-stats.json'}])

    config.devServer.public('http://0.0.0.0:8080').host('0.0.0.0').port(8080).https(false).headers({"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":["\*"]})
  },

  pages: {
    index: 'src/main.js'
  }
}
```

**This is an error on cmd.**

npm run serve

> django-vue@0.1.0 serve
> vue-cli-service serve

INFO  Starting development server...
ERROR  ValidationError: Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
- options has an unknown property 'public'. These properties are valid:
object { allowedHosts?, bonjour?, client?, compress?, devMiddleware?, headers?, historyApiFallback?, host?, hot?, http2?, https?, ipc?, liveReload?, magicHtml?, onAfterSetupMiddleware?, onBeforeSetupMiddleware?, onListening?, open?, port?, proxy?, server?, setupExitSignals?, setupMiddlewares?, static?, watchFiles?, webSocketServer? }
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.

- options has an unknown property 'public'. These properties are valid:
  object { allowedHosts?, bonjour?, client?, compress?, devMiddleware?, headers?, historyApiFallback?, host?, hot?, http2?, https?, ipc?, liveReload?, magicHtml?, onAfterSetupMiddleware?, onBeforeSetupMiddleware?, onListening?, open?, port?, proxy?, server?, setupExitSignals?, setupMiddlewares?, static?, watchFiles?, webSocketServer? }
  at validate (/Users/byengju/Documents/01. Project/dataglass/django-vue/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:115:11)
  at new Server (/Users/byengju/Documents/01. Project/dataglass/django-vue/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js:231:5)
  at serve (/Users/byengju/Documents/01. Project/dataglass/django-vue/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/commands/serve.js:194:20)
  at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

How do I solve it?

Comment: this happend when i only using node version 18. and still explore why

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, `public` is not a valid property where you have `config.devServer.public('http://0.0.0.0:8080')`.  It is a property from [webpack-dev-server v3](https://v4.webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverpublic) but based on your error message and the list of available property names, you are clearly on [webpack-dev-server v4](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/).

Ask yourself though:  do you *need* to specify what is normally the default devserver address, 0.0.0.0:8080 (localhost:8080)? Try just removing the property and test if your app works.  Usually such a property is only needed for proxy or websocket addresses.  The [migration guide](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/migration-v4.md) from v3 to v4 even says:

> public, sockHost, sockPath, and sockPort options were removed in favor client.webSocketURL option:

**v3:**

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    public: "ws://localhost:8080",
  },
};
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    sockHost: "0.0.0.0",
    sockPath: "/ws",
    sockPort: 8080,
  },
};
```

**v4:**

```js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    client: {
      // Can be `string`:
      //
      // To get protocol/hostname/port from browser
      // webSocketURL: 'auto://0.0.0.0:0/ws'
      webSocketURL: {
        hostname: "0.0.0.0",
        pathname: "/ws",
        port: 8080,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: My error is **options has an unknown property 'watchOptions'**

Comment: Did you add a property `watchOptions`?  I don't see it in the code in your question.  If it's anything like the first error, remember to only use properties/settings relevant to [webpack-dev-server v4](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/)... you can figure out how to update old v3 code with the [migration guide](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/migration-v4.md)

Comment: I uninstalled `webpack-dev-server` v4 and installed `webpack-dev-server` v3 instead, and still I get same error **options has an unknown property 'watchOptions'**.

Comment: I installed webpack 4 `npm install --save-dev webpack@4` instead of 5 and now it doesn't get that error but I get this error instead **ValidationError: Progress Plugin Invalid Options**

Comment: it's probably best to start fresh.  delete node_modules and reinstall dependencies.  start with all default webpack options and add your webpack options one at a time. make sure you're referencing the correct documentation and verifying correct functionality before adding additional options. small incremental updates are easier to fix when something goes wrong because you know exactly what code caused an issue!